# Firebase Auth Password Reset iOS Swift - Update Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

We use **Firebase Auth** & **Firebase Database** for user authentication.  For complex reasons, **we keep user passwords in both locations**.

**How do we UPDATE the Firebase Database /user node after the user has changed their password in Firebase AUTH?**

Is there a **completion block** in the Firebase Auth > Password Reset work flow that we can simply update Firebase Database with the new password?  I'm not sure if Firebase will pass the NEW PASSWORD to us to update in Firebase Database /user node.

One idea we had was to just update the user info in Firebase Auth using the '**`updatePassword`**' function, but Firebase says that if the user has not logged in for a while, then the user has to be re-authenticated.  So we're not sure how to work around that issue.

Any suggestions or thoughts or advice on the work flow?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Auth cannot reveal the users password. If you noticed no admin can get the users password through the Firebase Auth interface either.

I've tried doing this using cloud functions, but it didn't work either. If the user resets the password, it's completely between them and Firebase.

I guess you are setting the password yourself the first time, and then store it in the database. But there is no completion function for Auth that can retrieve the password the user just put in. For safety reasons.

if you are using the **updatePassword** function, the user must have write access to the node in the database that could store the password.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is I’m pretty sure it is:

```
Auth().auth.currentUser.changePassword...
```

If it is not just search online for changing user password swift and look at the Firebase documentation.